# What is the meaning of 'attempt to index upvalue'

Tags: lua, upvalue

I am taking my first steps programming in Lua and get this error when I run my script:

```
attempt to index upvalue 'base' (a function value)
```

It's probably due to something very basic that I haven't grasped yet, but I can't find any good information about it when googling. Could someone explain to me what it means?

Comment: Here are a couple of references for the term upvalue.  This page describes the concept with an example using an anonymous function http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html and this posting complains about the term upvalue suggesting an alternative http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-11/msg00243.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this case it looks `base` is a function, but you're trying to index it like a table (eg. `base[5]` or `base.somefield`).

The 'upvalue' part is just telling you what kind of variable `base` is, in this case an upvalue (aka external local variable).

Comment: Ah, yes of course - it was as simple as that. In my confusion I missed the obvious. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 12):

## One "local" too many?

As [Mike F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/195599/6286781) explained, an "upvalue" is an external local variable.  This error often occurs when a variable has been declared `local` in a forward declaration and then declared `local` **again** when it is initialized.  This leaves the forward declared variable with a value of `nil`.  This code snippet demonstrates what **not** to do:

```
 local foo -- a forward declaration 

 local function useFoo()
      print( foo.bar )  -- foo is an upvalue and this will produce the error in question
                        -- not only is foo.bar == nil at this point, but so is foo
 end

 local function f()

     -- one LOCAL too many coming up...

     local foo = {}   -- this is a **new** foo with function scope

     foo.bar = "Hi!"

     -- the local foo has been initialized to a table
     -- the upvalue (external local variable) foo declared above is not
     -- initialized

     useFoo()
 end 

 f()
```

In this case, removing the `local` in front of `foo` when it is initialized in `f()` fixes the example, i.e.

```
foo = {}
foo.bar = "Hi!"
```

Now the call to useFoo() will produce the desired output

> Hi!